# Creating a custom, "multiple dates picker" field

Tags: custom-fieldtype, custom-field, jquery

We're migrating* a website that uses http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/ to store any combination of dates for an entry... (eg not just a single date or date range, can be lots of individual dates which aren't sequential)

What would be the best kind of field/setup to import these into?

I guess we could create a custom field type that implements the same multipicker as above as it's also based on the jQuery datepicker widget... but have never created a custom field type from scratch though... what is the best approach to this?

(*7000 entries to import via FeedMe, looks like every single date is added to an event table as an individual row and looked up via an id :zany_face:)

[image]

Comment: Wondering if I can use an approach similar to https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-field-in-craft-cms, eg extend the existing date field and replace the vanilla datapicker UI with the multiselect one above....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I got this working fairly easily* by:

1. Creating a custom module and custom field type based on the default Plain Text Field (similar to https://nystudio107.com/blog/creating-a-custom-field-in-craft-cms)
2. Adding the https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI JS and CSS to an asset bundle as part of the same module
3. Within the new custom field, after the field has been set up, instantiating a Multiple Dates Picker instance at the end of the field html, and being sure to set the separator to just a comma (rather than the default comma followed by a space)

```
{% js %}
    $('#{{ id|namespaceInputId|e('js') }}').multiDatesPicker({
    separator: ","
  });
{% endjs %}
```

* Partly because the Multiple Dates Picker piggybacks the jQuery UI stuff that Craft already include in the control panel :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a custom field could you do it with a Matrix with each date going into a matrix row?

I've done something similar in the past for scheduling delivery dates for a Commerce order. Each order has a matrix field for delivery dates and each date (along with some other data) is added as a separate row.

Comment: That would work yes - only problem is for events that span 10-15 days it's quite a lot of work!

Comment: If it's specifically for events then have you considered using Verbb Events plugin instead? Although not sure how you'd get import the dates into it tbh.

Comment: Love a Verbb plugin! Most of the events have tickets on Eventbrite or other platforms already, the venue is basically aggregating a bunch of events that various organisations have already set up on these platforms